# how to send/receive xml data to service bus queue using service bus REST API in C#?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/send-message-to-queue) link, to send xml data to service bus queue successfully using service bus RESTAPI from advance rest API client and postman.

This is the XML data I want to send to queue:

```
<workItem>
<date>1408566000</date>
<duration>40</duration>
<desciption>test</desciption>
</workItem>
```

This is the C# code I wrote, to send xml data to queue. But whenever I am trying to receive the message from queue, I got the deserialization issues.

```
   public static async void sendMessagesToQueueUsingRESTAPI( string SASToken)
    {
        try
        {
            var url = "https://<namespace>.servicebus.windows.net/queue/messages";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            byte[] bytes;
            bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(envelope);
            //request.ContentType = "application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8";
            request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
            //request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8");
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", SASToken);
            //request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

            request.Method = "POST";
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
            HttpWebResponse response;
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
            {
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

   public static void receiveMessagesFromQueue()
    {
        //Receive messages from the queues
        var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(nsConnectionString, queuePath);
        client.OnMessage(message =>
        {

          Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Receive Message body: {0}",    message.GetBody<string>()));
          Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Receive Message id: {0}", message.MessageId));
        });

        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit program");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Can you please tell me how to send/receive xml data to service bus queue using service bus rest API in C#?

Comment: "I got the deserialization issues." Funny, I don't see any. Maybe you should [edit] and add details about what happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your receive code, `message.GetBody<string>()` does not just return `string` message as you expect. Instead, it is trying to deserialize your message using `DataContractSerializer` with a binary `XmlDictionaryWriter`. To read the message body as-is, you need to

```
using (var stream = message.GetBody<Stream>())
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    var body = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```